# Unknown CMake command "BISON_TARGET"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake, bison

I am trying to configure and generate a source code in Cmake to be able to run in MS Visual Studio 2010 but all I am getting is this error -Unknown CMake command "BISON_TARGET"-. Following is the output and the list of errors. I have BISON installed. Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?

```
The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10
Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
Could NOT find BISON (missing:  BISON_EXECUTABLE)  CMake Error at
src/parameters/CMakeLists.txt:16 (BISON_TARGET):   Unknown CMake command "BISON_TARGET".
```

Comment: Is bison in your path, so that it can be executed from the command line?

Answer (score 3):

Set `BISON_EXECUTABLE` from CMake GUI to proper executable path and reconfigure the cache.

Comment: There's no CMake GUI in linux. Can you please elaborate on how to do it in linux ? also how do I go about reconfiguring the cache?

Comment: @RichiDubey `cmake-gui` is a cross-platform app written in Qt. Anyways, to reconfigure the cache from command line, run `cmake .` in the build directory.

Answer (score 1):

In my windows 10 environment, I had to rename the following files:

- win_flex.exe --> flex.exe
- win_bison.exe --> bison.exe

Answer (score 1):

**Windows:**

I'm using Windows 10 and I had to download [WinBisonFlex](https://github.com/lexxmark/winflexbison/releases) binaries, extract the zip, and add the resulting folder to my system's path.

Note that you need to restart the application which generated the error (in your case Visual Studio).

**Docker:**

In my Docker container I needed to add:

```
# Install Bison Flex.
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    bison \
    flex
```

**Linux:**

The packages mentioned in the Docker container can off course also be installed in a Linux distro to solve the problem on a Linux machine.